# Замена двоеточия тире

Tags: синтаксис, тире

### Чего будет в мире больше – хорошего или плохого?

Возможно ли в данном предложении двоеточие заменить тире, для того чтобы обратить взор читателя именно на вторую часть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, для меня даже предпочтительно.

Одно из правил:

> Может быть поставлено тире вместо двоеточия после обобщающего слова
>   перед группой однородных членов, если однородные члены имеют характер
>   приложения или уточнения.
>   *Сказки любят все – и взрослые, и дети.* https://lektsia.com/1x61c7.html

*Чего будет в мире больше – хорошего или плохого?* Здесь явное уточнение, чего именно больше.